# Candy Box 2 - The Computer doesn't work on phone

Tags: candy-box-2

I can't use the computer on my phone because you need to press the <kbd>enter</kbd> button but I am playing on the phone. How can I press this button?

Comment: What sort of phone are you using? iPhone or an Android?